# Avoid registering duplicate broadcast receivers with work manager

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, android-workmanager

I am doing a repetitive Bluetooth scan in the background and recording results in room DB on each scan.

I am using Work Manager to initiate the Bluetooth scan and also register the broadcast receiver in it for Bluetooth discovery complete action.

On completion of Bluetooth discovery, I am initiating a new scan, and the process repeats.

If the Bluetooth scan is already happening, I still want to register a broadcast receiver and continue recording results from there.

Now the issue is that when I use the following function startBluetoothDiscovery(context) from inside doWork() of CoroutineWorker, sometimes there are duplicate broadcast receivers (same data being recorded multiple times on discovery completion)

```
private fun startBluetoothDiscovery(context: Context) {

    val adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
    if (adapter != null && adapter.isEnabled) {

        if (!adapter.isDiscovering) {

            registerBluetoothReceiver(context)
            adapter.startDiscovery()

        } else {

            registerBluetoothReceiver(context)
        }
    }
}

private fun registerBluetoothReceiver(context: Context) {
    val intentFilter = IntentFilter().apply {
        addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)
        addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED)
    }

    context.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter)
}
```

I am trying to find a way to ensure that there is only 1 broadcast receiver registered at a time (no duplicates), I have tried many things including following:

```
public class ReceiverManager {
private WeakReference<Context> cReference;
private static List<BroadcastReceiver> receivers = new ArrayList<>();
private static ReceiverManager ref;

private ReceiverManager(Context context) {
    cReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
}

public static synchronized ReceiverManager init(Context context) {
    if (ref == null) ref = new ReceiverManager(context);
    return ref;
}

public Intent registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter intentFilter) {
    receivers.add(receiver);
    Intent intent = cReference.get().registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "registered receiver: " + receiver + "  with filter: " + intentFilter);
    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "receiver Intent: " + intent);
    return intent;
}

public boolean isReceiverRegistered(BroadcastReceiver receiver) {
    boolean registered = receivers.contains(receiver);
    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "is receiver " + receiver + " registered? " + registered);
    return registered;
}

public void unregisterReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver) {
    if (isReceiverRegistered(receiver)) {
        receivers.remove(receiver);
        cReference.get().unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "unregistered receiver: " + receiver);
    }
}
```

}

and changing the else part of code from startBluetoothDiscovery(context) to following:

```
else if (!ReceiverManager.init(context).isReceiverRegistered(receiver)) {

            registerBluetoothReceiver(context)
        }
```

Any suggestions about how to avoid getting duplicate broadcast receivers in this scenario?